# How to get product price, condition using Amazon MWS API

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I am using amazon MWS API's end point
[GetMyPriceForSKU](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMyPriceForSKU.html)
but it returns empty offers if we do not have offers which contains item condition, price etc.
Instead, I want to get product price, item conditions even we do not have offers. How can I get my product price, condition info without "GetMyPriceForSKU" ? 
I am using [ScrachPad](https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html) in order to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement notifications service. Take a look at:
[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/mwsportal/doc/en_US/notifications/MWSPushNotificationsApiReference.*V343959826*.pdf](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/mwsportal/doc/en_US/notifications/MWSPushNotificationsApiReference._V343959826_.pdf)

they have shutted down the price infos apis,because of this new api.